What is the proof that $x^{a+b} = x^a x^b$?
What is the proof that $x^{a+b} = x^a x^b$ ?
I believe this is called the exponentiation identity

reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function
see: The functions
${\displaystyle f(x)=b^{x}}$ for positive real numbers
${\displaystyle b}$ are also known as exponential functions, and satisfy the exponentiation identity

I have known about it for a long time, but don't recall if I have ever seen a proof of this.
There is a proof which works for integer values of $a$, $b$ which is the following:

$x^a$ = $\underbrace{x\cdot x\cdot x \cdot\dots\cdot x}_{\text{a times}}$
$x^b$ = $\underbrace{x\cdot x\cdot x \cdot\dots\cdot x}_\text{b times}$

therefore

$\begin{align*} x^a x^b &= \underbrace{\underbrace{ x \cdot\dots\cdot x}_\text{a times}\underbrace{\cdot x\cdot \dots \cdot x}_\text{b times}}_\text{a+b times}\\
&=x^{a+b}\end{align*}$

Solution
I personally feel that all the (linked) answers to this question are very unclear, so I will provide a short explanation here to make it exactly clear:

$x^ax^b=x^{a+b}$ is true for integers because we defined $x^a$ to mean $x$ multiplied by itself $a$ times
It makes sense to write down on paper the symbol $x$ multiplied by itself an integer number of times
It does not make sense to write down on paper the symbol $x$ multiplied by itself a non-integer number of times
But this is not a problem, because we use this as an abstract concept
To circle back: Really what we are doing is this:

We define $x\times x$ to be $x^2$
We then move forward and define $x \times x \times x\hat{=} x^3$ where the hat symbol means is defined to be
We continue for arbitrary integer $n$ such that $\underbrace{x\cdot x\cdot x \cdot\dots\cdot x}_\text{n times}\hat{=}x^n$
Finally, we abstract upwards and say that if we could write down an expression on paper for $x$ multiplied by itself $y$ times, where $y$ is a non-integer number, then we would write this as $x^y$, which happens to be something we can write on paper.

Conclusion
There is no real proof here as such, it is more like by definition this is what $x^y$ means, for $y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Additional
From here it is relatively easy to prove other identities. For example:

$x^a=x^{a+0}=x^a x^0$ and from this $x^0\hat{=}1$

Now we have an identity for $x^0$ we can use this to get an identity for division.

$x^0=x^{0+b-b}=x^0 x^b x^{-b}=1\times x^b x^{-b}$ and since $x^0=$ we have $1=x^b\times x^{-b}$ and from this we define $x^{-b}=\frac{1}{x^b}$

Further: If $b=1$ we have $x^{-1}=\frac{1}{x^1}=\frac{1}{x}$ hence from the above bullet point $x^{-b}=\left(x^b\right)^{-1}$

Or, if you don't like that argument, we can do $x^{-b}=x^{-1\times b}$. At this point we need to introduce a new identity, which I do not show a proof of here but the reader can surely derive for himself, $x^{a\times b}=\left(x^a\right)^b=\left(x^b\right)^a$, therefore $x^{-b}=\left(x^b\right)^{-1}$



Your integer proof can easily be adapted to prove it for rational numbers. And then you can invoke continuity of exponentiation to prove it for real numbers.

@TonyK at least for positive rational numbers.

@YvesDaoust It does, if taken in combination with a "proof" of $x^ax^b$ for integer a, b


it is just an accepted convention - yes, this is exactly what I have stated in my question/answer

